# Optimized Way to Splice Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, pandas, cython

My problem is I have a very large time series (~5-10 million obs) that have certain events marked with flags. In this case it is a drop in stock prices that triggers an event that has a dummy variable for that is 1 or 0 if the event is triggered or not. From this time series I would like to extract both the events themselves and the subsequent 29 days of data. Obviously, this involves some type of splicing of arrays.

I have some simple code which should do the trick (it merely marks the flags and the next 29 days as 2 but from there it is simple to filter the dataframe) but it relies on pandas dataframe splicing which is not very quick. Here is the code:

```
def first_drop(df):
    indexlen = len(df.dropflag[df.dropflag==1].index)

    for y in range(indexlen):                                                                                                                           
            x = df.dropflag[df.dropflag==1].index[y]
            df.dropflag[x:30]=2

    return df.dropflag

dstk['dropflag2'] = dstk[["permno","dropflag"]].groupby('permno').apply(first_drop)
```

Is there a faster way anyone else has found to do this type of splicing where you get the next x number of entries? I am thinking it is maybe faster with numpy arrays or maybe a cythonized function but I can't quite see where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible way to do it. Maybe not so fast, it takes 1 min to process a 10,000,000 row dataset. The idea is that, by populating new columns with data on subsequent days using `.shift(-i)`, it avoids looping over rows inside each `groupby`. Its advantage is the flexibility on reshaping the resulting dataframe, for example `stack()` to get stacked records.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate some artificial data, 10,000,000 rows
# ============================================================
np.random.seed(0)
dates = pd.date_range('2001-01-01', periods=2500, freq='B')
permno = np.arange(1000, 5000)  # 4000 symbols
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([permno, dates], names=['permno', 'dates'])
data = np.random.randn(10000000)
dropflag = np.random.choice([0,1], size=10000000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data, 'dropflag': dropflag}, index=multi_index).reset_index('permno')

Out[273]: 
            permno    data  dropflag
dates                               
2001-01-01    1000  1.7641         1
2001-01-02    1000  0.4002         1
2001-01-03    1000  0.9787         0
2001-01-04    1000  2.2409         1
2001-01-05    1000  1.8676         0
...            ...     ...       ...
2010-07-26    4999  0.5902         1
2010-07-27    4999  0.4676         1
2010-07-28    4999 -1.9447         1
2010-07-29    4999 -0.3440         1
2010-07-30    4999 -0.7402         0

[10000000 rows x 3 columns]

# processing
# ============================================================
def func(group):
    all_data = [group]
    for i in np.arange(1, 30):
        temp = group.data.shift(-i)
        temp.name = 'data_subday{}'.format(i)
        all_data.append(temp)
    dataset = pd.concat(all_data, axis=1).iloc[:-30]
    return dataset.loc[dataset.dropflag==1]

%time df.groupby('permno').apply(func)

CPU times: user 59.7 s, sys: 1.83 s, total: 1min 1s
Wall time: 1min 5s


Out[277]: 
                   permno    data  dropflag  data_subday1  data_subday2      ...        data_subday25  data_subday26  data_subday27  data_subday28  data_subday29
permno dates                                                                 ...                                                                                 
1000   2001-01-01    1000  1.7641         1        0.4002        0.9787      ...              -1.4544         0.0458        -0.1872         1.5328         1.4694
       2001-01-02    1000  0.4002         1        0.9787        2.2409      ...               0.0458        -0.1872         1.5328         1.4694         0.1549
       2001-01-04    1000  2.2409         1        1.8676       -0.9773      ...               1.5328         1.4694         0.1549         0.3782        -0.8878
       2001-01-08    1000 -0.9773         1        0.9501       -0.1514      ...               0.1549         0.3782        -0.8878        -1.9808        -0.3479
       2001-01-09    1000  0.9501         1       -0.1514       -0.1032      ...               0.3782        -0.8878        -1.9808        -0.3479         0.1563
...                   ...     ...       ...           ...           ...      ...                  ...            ...            ...            ...            ...
4999   2010-06-09    4999  2.1195         1        1.5564        1.0739      ...               0.2677         1.2637        -0.3607        -1.4011         1.1292
       2010-06-15    4999 -1.1747         1        0.2159        0.1221      ...               1.1292         1.1614         0.4842         1.3593         0.5902
       2010-06-16    4999  0.2159         1        0.1221        0.0136      ...               1.1614         0.4842         1.3593         0.5902         0.4676
       2010-06-17    4999  0.1221         1        0.0136        0.8378      ...               0.4842         1.3593         0.5902         0.4676        -1.9447
       2010-06-18    4999  0.0136         1        0.8378        0.4887      ...               1.3593         0.5902         0.4676        -1.9447        -0.3440

[4941409 rows x 32 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! It took me a second to figure out what exactly you were doing there but then it clicked pretty fast. One thing though, the original code I had overwrites all the 1's within 30 days, so if another dropflag==1 is within 30 days it does not get calculated. Is there a way to filter your results above so only the first dropflag==1 within 30 days gets calculated?

Comment: Btw that was a good way to avoid iterating over every element.

Comment: Nevermind. I found a way to do it using your answer. Just find the date difference in days between each date and the previous date and drop if the difference is less than 30 days. Thanks. Accepting your answer.